# Load PowerPoint file in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a PPT viewer app.I have added the pptViewer library in my project from https://github.com/itsrts/pptviewer-android.
But I am getting an error called "cannot resolve symbol 'activity'" on this line  pptViewer.loadPPT(activity,"/home/waheed/lab6.pptx").Please help.
Below is my code:

```
   package com.example.waheed.myapplication;

   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;

   import com.itsrts.pptviewer.PPTViewer;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PPTViewer pptViewer = (PPTViewer) findViewById(R.id.pptviewer);
    pptViewer.setNext_img(R.drawable.next)
            .setPrev_img(R.drawable.prev)
            .setSettings_img(R.drawable.settings)
            .setZoomin_img(R.drawable.zoomin)
            .setZoomout_img(R.drawable.zoomout);
    pptViewer.loadPPT(activity,"/home/waheed/lab6.pptx");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activity` isn't a  defined symbol, but . In this case, since the code is in an activity, use the current object:

```
pptViewer.loadPPT(this, "/home/waheed/lab6.pptx");
```

You probably copy-pasted from the readme, as the `activity` used as sample method input in the readme means you have to pass an activity instance. You don't declare `Activity activity = ...`, but since you're in an activity you can use `this`

Answer (score 0):

```
pptViewer.loadPPT(this,"/home/waheed/lab6.pptx");
```

Comment: @KapilRajput this is the code fragment which will fix author's problem, so it's an answer

Comment: it is an answer, but it's very low quality. Just a snippet without any explanation isn't likely to OP

Comment: Code-only answers are very seldom useful. Please explain how your snippet answers the question. For us all to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You reference `activity`  in your code which is not defined. Pass current class  instead of the undefined field.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PPTViewer pptViewer = (PPTViewer) findViewById(R.id.pptviewer);
    pptViewer.setNext_img(R.drawable.next)
            .setPrev_img(R.drawable.prev)
            .setSettings_img(R.drawable.settings)
            .setZoomin_img(R.drawable.zoomin)
            .setZoomout_img(R.drawable.zoomout);
    pptViewer.loadPPT(MainActivity.this,"/home/waheed/lab6.pptx");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.But I am still unable to open the file.I mean, it shows the loading bar forever in the Android Emulator.Please help me if you can:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pptViewer.loadPPT(MainActivity.this,"/home/waheed/lab6.pptx");
```