# Import a pdf document from assets into a PdfDocument object

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdfdocument

I have managed to create my own pdf documents with the help of PdfDocument Class.
But what if I already have a pdf in my (let's say) assets folder and I want to e.g. draw something on it. Is it possible?

I have my

```
PdfDocument document;
```

But how can i read the powerpoint i have inside my project?

I am guessing i have to use a `File` but i cannot work this out.

I tried something like this, although I know it is wrong

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(getAssets().open("powerpoint"));
```

Comment: About what filetype are you talking here? *.ppt or pptx? Or did you talk about a converted powerpoint file which is now a pdf file?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you ask two questions:

1. > But what if I already have a pdf in my (let's say) assets folder and I
   >   want to e.g. draw something on it. Is it possible?

With the android [PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) class, you can create a PDF out of Web content (via WebView), a Canvas (using views or the native Canvas drawing API), or an image. You have to use third-party PDF libraries (like [iText](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/installation-guides/installing-itext-g-android) or the [PDFBox Android port](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android)) to change existing PDFs.

2. > But how can i read the powerpoint i have inside my project?

For displaying powerpoint there is a separate project called '[pptviewer-android](https://github.com/itsrts/pptviewer-android)'. However it is not maintained anymore, so if you have problems you probably have to figure those out by yourself. An examplary use can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280243/load-powerpoint-file-in-android).

```
PPTViewer pptViewer = (PPTViewer) findViewById(R.id.pptviewer);
pptViewer.setNext_img(R.drawable.next)
        .setPrev_img(R.drawable.prev)
        .setSettings_img(R.drawable.settings)
        .setZoomin_img(R.drawable.zoomin)
        .setZoomout_img(R.drawable.zoomout);
pptViewer.loadPPT(this,"/home/powerpoint.pptx");
```

Comment: Could you give example to write on top of the existing PDF

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I have correctly understood your problem statement:
Please try this out:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
try {
    File fileToOpen = new File("/assets/file.pdf");
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(fileToOpen);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // log Error
}
}
```